# Why does WHO have a constitution?

Tags: constitution, who

So, while doing some research on on the World Health Organization (WHO), I noticed it had a [constitution](https://www.who.int/governance/eb/who_constitution_en.pdf).

I found this weird, because I always had associated the word "Constitution" with countries, not organizations. For instance, the United States has a [Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_the_United_States), as do [many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_constitutions) too numerous to list here.

It's my understanding that the WHO is an organization (hence, the o in its name) and is [a part of the United Nations](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/06/27/insider/the-who-versus-the-cdc.html), not a sovereign nation. So why exactly does it have a constitution? Why exactly do they choose this word, as opposed to something like "bylaws" instead?

---

*Edit*: I seem to have drawn some confusion on what I'm asking here. I'm not asking for the dictionary definition of "Constitution." I'm what about it makes it a "Constitution." Is that just the name that they chose, or is there another reason?

Comment: "A constitution is a framework for government, and serves as a set of founding principles for the entity." - *entity*, not county.

Comment: Other UN specialized agencies have one too, e.g. the FAO and the ILO.

Comment: @Relaxed: it would in fact be a more interesting q if any UN org sub-org uses a different term. The IMF calls its thing a "charter" informally (fromally it's Articles of Agreement).

Comment: The use of the term might be related to https://brill.com/view/title/16385

Comment: @Fizz That link would make a good answer. Do you want to turn it into one and get credit for it?

Comment: I said "might". It's a recent book. I don't know if the decades old use of "constitution" for FAO / ILO / WHO is in that vein or not... The book might have details (on that too), but I haven't read it.

Comment: The ILO "constitution" is [from 1919](https://research.un.org/en/docs/unsystem/ilo), although the WHO's is only from '45. UNESCO also has a Constitution (also '45). Even the later-established [UNIDO](https://research.un.org/en/docs/unsystem/unido) adoped a "Consittion" in 1979.

Comment: The "ILO Constitution constituted Part XIII of the Treaty of Versailles". So it probably has something to do with the usage/language at the time, probably influenced by the French legal tradition. Also ILO had a bit more real power between the wars https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3505276

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be a basic language question, answerable with a dictioanry.

Comment: My school club had a constitution. Constitution has been used to constitute companies and organizations for a long time and *by no means whatsoever* restricted to nations. I would say trying to trace the choice of word is an overanalysis. "Company constitution", "Constitution of xxx debate club" etc. are all contemporary, accepted English usages (see e.g. [1](https://www.drew.edu/StudentActivities/information-on-starting-a-new-club/sample-club-constitution), [2](https://legalvision.com.au/what-is-a-company-constitution-what-does-it-mean-to-adopt-a-company-constitution/)).

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia states that:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution)

> A constitution is an aggregate of fundamental principles or established precedents that constitute the legal basis of a polity, organisation or other type of entity, and commonly determine how that entity is to be governed. ...
>
> A treaty which establishes an international organization is also its constitution, in that it would define how that organization is constituted.

So, although the most famous constitutions are all for states, it is not a requirement. Any organization built around a set of fundamental principles can have a constitution.